# Magento products are not in grid

Tags: magento-1.9, product, grid

My products are not on one line at this page: http://www.graffitistiften.nl/index.php/alpha-design-marker.html
[image: see picture]

How can is change this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Its css issue Not magento issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, You need to edit styles.css file.

```
http://www.graffitistiften.nl/skin/frontend/tv_arion_package/tv_arion/css/styles.css
```

Line no 666, there is a class `.products-grid li.item` replace this class

```
.products-grid li.item {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

with

```
.products-grid li.item {
    min-height: 368px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You need to set the min-height of the block. So it will look same in all rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is only the hight issue. You have to set equal hight for each product block and for this the product name should have equal length.

To achieve this you have to truncate the product name or set the height of the the product name `html` and over flow `hidden` for that...like

`.product_name{height:40px; overflow :hidden}`